# PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column ERROR with pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, pandasql

I'm trying to get a column from a `dataframe` with pandasql command:

```
import yfinance as yf
from pandasql import *
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
yf.pdr_override()

list_of_companies = 'GOOG,TSLA'

class Analyzer():

    def __init__(self,companies):
        self.companies = companies
        self.yahoo_data = self.load_ystock_data(self.companies)
        self.data_sets = {"yahoo_data": self.yahoo_data}

    def load_ystock_data(self,companies_list):
        data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(companies_list, period='1d')
        return data

    def query(self, q):
        return sqldf(q,self.data_sets)

a = Analyzer(list_of_companies)

query_statement = """
                    SELECT
                    Close
                    FROM
                    yahoo_data;
                  """  
df1 = a.query(query_statement)
```

but retrieve the error:

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Close
>   [SQL: 
>                       SELECT
>                       Close
>                       FROM
>                       yahoo_data;
>                     ]

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with case sensitivity when using Column Name. 
Try enclosing the column name Close in "" such as:

```
query_statement = """
                    SELECT
                    'Close'
                    FROM
                    yahoo_data;
                  """
```